# Where is the Name option in dynamic paint canvas v 2.79

Tags: dynamic-paint

I am trying to follow this ["Freezing/Frost Text Effect"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BvY2L6zl7k) tutorial from version 2.65 on how to add frost to text.  At 3 min 47 sec he changes the name of the canvas in the dynamic paint section.  I don't see that option in 2.79[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse click twice on default *Surface* name to enter rename-function.